# Go.JS Diagram Add Javascript Array Object Not Working As Expected No Hash ID

Tags: javascript, gojs

This must be a formatting issue, but my graph is not accepting new data from the real source... I noticed there is not hash ID being generated by Go.js

```
 function updateGraph(node_list,myDiagram){
        var model = $(go.TreeModel);
        //add some dummy data
          model.nodeDataArray =
        [
         { key: 1, parent: 1, color: "lightblue"},
         { key: 2, parent: 1 , color: "lightblue"},
         { key: 3, parent: 2, color: "lightblue"}
        ];
        //add real data
        for(let id = 1; id < node_list.length; id++){
            model.nodeDataArray.push({key: node_list[id].getNodeID(), parent: node_list[id].getNodeID(),  color: "lightblue"});
        }
        console.log(model.nodeDataArray);
        myDiagram.model = model;
    }
```

Console:

```
0: {key: 1, parent: 1, color: "lightblue", __gohashid: 409}
1: {key: 2, parent: 1, color: "lightblue", __gohashid: 410}
2: {key: 3, parent: 2, color: "lightblue", __gohashid: 411}
3: {key: "step_02_set_incoming_file_permissions", parent: "step_02_set_incoming_file_permissions", color: "lightblue"}
4: {key: "step_025_truncate", parent: "step_025_truncate", color: "lightblue"}
5: {key: "step_03_extract_item_sold_details", parent: "step_03_extract_item_sold_details", color: "lightblue"}
```

[image: Go.js not displaying real data]

---

However, if I set the dummy data to hardcoded values being printed out by the console:

```
  model.nodeDataArray =
    [
   {key: "step_02_set_incoming_file_permissions", parent: "step_01_starting_email", color: "lightblue"},
   {key: "step_025_truncate", parent: "step_02_set_incoming_file_permissions", color: "lightblue"},
   {key: "step_03_extract_item_sold_details", parent: "step_025_truncate", color: "lightblue"}
    ];
```

I get an  output with hash id's:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so Go.JS requires another function to add data properly. You can't just feed it dymanic object for some reason... Calling the method `addNodeData` as per [Go.JS documentation](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html) fixed the graphing issue!

```
 model.addNodeData({key: node_list[id].getNodeID(), parent: node_list[id].getNodeID(),  color: "lightblue"});
 model.addLinkData( { from: node_list[id].getNodeID(), to: node_list[id].getNextNode() } ); //link data
```

Comment: Yes, that's because GoJS does not waste time trying to find differences between data structures.  So you either need to explicitly call **Model.set** (in the standard organization using plain JavaScript Objects) or you need to implement smarter property setters that call **Model.set**.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods Thanks, I ended up doing extra research. Appreciate the info!